# How to get output stream back from PDFwriter in case of exception

Tags: jakarta-ee, struts, itext

i am facing the problem of response already committed, because while creating PDF if some kind of error occurred then it throws the exception and exception handler tries to forward it to some error area. please help me how can i discard the current processing of file and acquire the response?

Thanks in Advance

**Edit**

```
PdfWriter pdfWriter = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, outputStream);
pdfWriter.setPageEvent(new PageEvents()); 
createPDF(document, fileName, headerNames, headerValues, imageNameList, pageType);     
document.close(); 
outputStream.close();
```

if error occured in `createPDF()`, like image not found,then it catch the `DocumentException` exception and throws the custom exception to action class and action class tries to forwad respons like this

```
catch (CustomException e) {
    String csvText = Message.PDF_NOT_GENERATED; 
    forward = mapping.findForward("displayError");
    return (forward); 
}
```

but due to pdfwriter, as outputstream is occupied by writer, server throws *response already committed* error on console

Comment: Can you at least post some code that reproduces the problem? What Exception handler are you talking about? What do you mean by "acquire the response"?

Comment: let me explain you more briefly. while creating PDF, if PdfWriter didn't find the proper image using `Image image = Image.getInstance(imageName);` then it throws `DocumentException` and in catch area it throws the custom exception to the caller and caller tries to forward response to error page, but due to pdfwriter, as outputstream is occupied by writer, server throws _response already committed_ error on console. hope now you will understand

Comment: Again, please post a whole piece of code, not just single lines. Also, you would rather edit your question than post extra information in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

Create a finally block where  close output stream, for example:

```
finally {
   if(outStream != null) {
            try {
                outStream.flush();
                outStream.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                res.setStatus(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR.value());
                throw new Exception(e);
            }
}
```